# child node is treated as grand child node when trying to structure

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-mptt

I am using `django-mptt` library for the category. I could show the list of categories in template but I wanted to indent it properly so user can know which is a main category and which one is sub-category and etc. The way i tried to structure is

```
{% recursetree nodes %}
  <li class="node">
    <a href="/category/{{ node.get_absolute_url }}"
      class="{% if not node.is_leaf_node and not node.is_root_node and node.is_child_node %} child_parent {% elif node.is_leaf_node and not node.is_root_node %}leaf_node{% endif %}">
      {{ node.name }}
      {% if node.is_root_node %}
        <span class="badge">{{ node.get_count_children }}</span>
      {% endif %}
    </a>
      {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
          <ul class="children">
            <li>{{ children }}</li>
          </ul>
      {% endif %}
  </li>
{% endrecursetree %}
```

This yields the following design of category

[image]

Here Dressing Table is a child of Bedroom Items like Bed and Almirah not a child of Bed. How could i fix this? I know the problem is here

```
<a href="/category/{{ node.get_absolute_url }}"
class="{% if not node.is_leaf_node and not node.is_root_node and node.is_child_node %} child_parent {% elif node.is_leaf_node and not node.is_root_node %}leaf_node{% endif %}">
```

but could not fix this issue

Not the dressing table in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `Dressing Table` is a `root` node?

Comment: No, `dressing table` is a child of bedroom items (to quote)

Comment: Then then render is correct already. `dressing table ` is a child of bedroom node. What is your expected structure?

Comment: Its not me, but I'm guessing its supposed to be rendered like `Bed` and `Almirah`, again I quote from the line under the image.

Comment: OK. I got the situation now. He needs to determine the leaf node. But that leaf node is the 2nd level from the root node. So he needs `Dressing Table` to be a `cyan` color.

Comment: He needs a customized `tag` that make use method `get_children` or pass `get_children` that return `boolean` in the `context`.

Comment: I have updated my question with the screenshot on how it should look like.

Comment: @Sarit exactly. I want Dressing Table to be a cyan color with the same indentation level a bed and almirah has because its a child node(child node and also a leaf node because it has no children).

Comment: @Serenity I am now following your question, but get this issue. If you know how to solve this. It will speed up me reaching your question. https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/issues/614

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to you updated answer. 
`Dinning Set, Kitchen Rack, and Kitchen Setup(Modular Kitchen)` are supposed to be `cyan` since they are second level.
If my understanding is correct.
Here is my hacked solution. If anybody found the better one please raise.

1. Add extra method to the `Model` instance
2. I have to add `nodes` to the `context`. (This would be an optional if you are using Django2.0 like mine)
3. Use the instance method in the template

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey


class Genre(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    def is_second_node(self):
        return True if (self.get_ancestors().count() == 1) else False
```

`views.py`

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

from genres.models import Genre


class GenreListView(ListView):
    model = Genre
    template_name = 'genre_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        """Get the context for this view."""
        queryset = object_list if object_list is not None else self.object_list
        page_size = self.get_paginate_by(queryset)
        context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(queryset)
        if page_size:
            paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
            context = {
                'paginator': paginator,
                'page_obj': page,
                'is_paginated': is_paginated,
                'object_list': queryset
            }
        else:
            context = {
                'paginator': None,
                'page_obj': None,
                'is_paginated': False,
                'object_list': queryset
            }
        if context_object_name is not None:
            context[context_object_name] = queryset
        context.update(kwargs)
        context['nodes'] = context.get('object_list')
        return super().get_context_data(**context)
```

`genre_list.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load mptt_tags %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Genre ListView</title>
</head>
<style>
    .root {color: purple}
    .child{color: cyan}
    .leaf {color: gray}
</style>
<body>
    {% recursetree nodes %}
    <div class="
        {% if node.is_root_node %}
        root
        {% elif node.is_child_node and not node.is_leaf_node or node.is_second_node%}
        child
        {% elif node.is_leaf_node and not node.is_root_node%}
        leaf
        {%endif%}">
        {{node.name}}
        {{node.is_second_node}}
    </div>
    {% if not node.is_leaf_node%}
    <ul>{{children}}</ul>
    {% endif %}

    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was struggling for. Thanks for your effort and knowledge.